# Select using ng-option is not updating model in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following array:

```
[{
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "A"
 },
 {
  "Id": 3,
  "Name": "B"
 },
 {
   "Id": 3,
   "Name": "C"
 }]
```

I am using this in the following Angular view:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="category.Name for category in categories"></select>
 <pre>{{selectedCategory | json}}</pre>

 <button type="button" ng-click="move()">Move</button>
```

The controller looks like:

```
var moveCategoryController = function ($scope, category, categoriesService) {

   var getCategories = function () {
    categoriesService.getCategories()
        .success(function (result) {

           $scope.categories = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < result.Results.length; i++) {
                var cat = result.Results[i];
                if (cat.Id !== category.Id) {
                    $scope.categories.push(cat);
                }
            }

            $scope.selectedCategory = $scope.categories[0];
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.errorMessage = "There was a problem loading the categories.";
        });
    };

    getCategories();


    $scope.move = function () {
         alert($scope.selectedCategory.Name);
    };

 }

 bpApp.controller("moveCategoryController", moveCategoryController);
```

*For info, the `category` object injected into the controller is a category object (the controller is being used in a modal and the category is passed to it from the parent page).*

**The Problem**

On loading, the select is bound to the data fine, and when the user changes the select list the `<pre>` content updates correctly with the newly selected category.

The problem is when I click the Move button, which calls the `move()` function on the controller scope, the `selectedCategory` property of the scope has not been updated.  For example, if I select the category "B", the alert still pops up with "A".

So, it seems that the `ng-model` is updated in the view, but not in the controller?!

Comment: could you make a fiddle.Actually I checked you code with your static data and it works for me.

Comment: A plunker/fiddle would be nice yes

Comment: Also, this may be caused by different scopes being created with your modal, how does that part look?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code; If you get updated value inside the <pre> element while changing the selected list options, you will also get the updated value while calling 'move()' method

Comment: hey @Graham could you update us on this?